# Facebook Like button not displaying using div tag

Tags: html, facebook

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
This the Javascript SDK!!
<script>(function(d, s, id) 
{var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if(d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
</body>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/tok2md" 
data-width="200" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like"
data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

I am trying to get facebook like button using div tag.
    But nothing shows up  on page.I tried doing using 
    iframe then it was displaying.Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need add your app-id on javascript after &**version=v2.5**

Must be like this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=XXXXXXXXXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

**XXXXXX** are your app-id

Because facebook not using anymore box like they are call this page plugin you can read on here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

That's mean if you want to use this kind like plugin "like box" you need also add your domain on that facebook app.

Comment: Ok thanx.I tried using app-id .But still doesn't display. .

Comment: If you are using chrome open the web tools and look error writing there why it's not showing.